# how to generate custom keyboard in web application for android and IOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, web-applications, responsive-design

I am looking for a custom keyboard to be generated on click of field in web application (responsive design)

`<input type="text" pattern="">` or `<input type="number" pattern="">` in mobile and tablets.

Currently I am getting that keyboard with numbers, but I want the user can also enter `'/'` along with the numbers. That means suppose if I want the user to enter date in  some field so it should accept `'/'` or `'-'` also along with the numbers. (01/01/2000 or 01-01-2000)

How can I do this ??

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: For android case, you can use a `TextWatcher` and allow only desired characters to be entered in `EditText` field. Or do you want expected characters to be visible in keyboard only? Maybe for that you have to write your own Input Method Editor.